# Uploadify onUploadSuccess not returning my data

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpresponse, uploadify

On the backend I'm sending: `res.send(JSON.stringify(back));` where `back`, after being stringified is:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"success":true,"data":{"name":"-kkWjmTLb","version":1,"dateCreated":1407448946239,"dateUpdated":1407448946239,"vidLoc":"rtmp://xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/vid_-kkWjmTLb","thumbLoc":"https://xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/big_icon.png","author":"53a47a469c52c9d83a2d71d9","videoBucket":"xx.xxxxxxxx","thumbBucket":"xx.xxxxxxxx","scenario":false,"fakeName":xxxxxxxxxx.flv"}}}
```

`

On the frontend I'm doing this:

```
$(htmlId).uploadify('settings','onUploadSuccess', function(file, data, res) {
            console.log('uploadSuccess',data);
```

And the console log tells me that `data` is `OK`

Not that big string up there, but simply `OK`.

How can I get my string to the frontend as a response to uploadify?

---

The full bakend code:

```
app.post('/uploadVideo',function(req,res){
    console.log("hit video upload");
    checkProperties(req.query,['name','ext','tenant'],function(results){
        if(!results.error){
            var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
            form.uploadDir = __dirname+'/uploads';
            form.keepExtensions = true;

            console.log('queries are ',req.query);

            form.on('file',function(field,file){
                var data = {};
                var uid = shortId.generate();
                var renamed = form.uploadDir + "/vid_"+uid;
                fs.rename(file.path,renamed);

                if(typeof req.query.tenant !== 'undefined'){
                    console.log('setting data');
                    data.tenant = req.query.tenant;
                    data.fakeName = req.query.name;
                    data.name = uid;
                    console.log('data set',data);
                }else{
                    console.log('no tenant');
                    res.send(400);
                    return;
                }

                console.log('calling uploadVideoS3',data);
                uploadVideoS3(renamed,req.query.ext,data,fs.readFileSync(renamed),function(back){
                    if(back.success){
                        console.log('done uploaded to S3',JSON.stringify(back));
                        res.send(JSON.stringify(back)); 
                    }else{
                        console.log('video upload S3 failed');
                        res.send(400);
                    }
                });
            });

            form.on('error',function(err){
                console.log("error with file upload " + err);
                res.send(400);
                res.end();
            });

            form.on('end',function(){
                console.log("done");
            });

            form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
                res.send(200);
                res.end();
            });
        }else{
            res.send(400);
            res.send(results.message);
        }
    });
});
```

The frontend code:

```
$scope.initVideoUploader = function(){
        uploadifyService.videoUploadInit('#videoUpload',function(back){
            if(back.data){
                console.log('file selected is:',back.data.name);
                var name = back.data.name; 
                var ext = back.data.name.substring(back.data.name.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
                uploadifyService.uploadVideo('#videoUpload',name,ext);
            }

            if(back.identifier){
                console.log(back);
                // var item = _.findWhere($scope.content.myContent.videos, {name: recorderInfo.id.toString()});
                // console.log(recorderInfo.id, item);
                // $scope.content.openItem(item);
            }
        });
    };
```

uploadifyService.js:

```
videoUploadInit: function(htmlId,callback){
            $(htmlId).uploadify({
                'scriptAccess': 'always',
                'multi': false,
                'auto': true,
                'swf': '/js/plugins/uploadify.swf',
                'buttonText': 'Upload Video',
                'fileTypeExts': '*.flv;',
                'fileSizeLimit': '20MB', 
                'onSelect': function(file, queueId) {
                    console.log('videoUploadInit onSelect hit');
                    callback({
                        data: file,
                        queueId: queueId
                    });
                },
                'onUploadSuccess': function(file, data, res) {
                    console.log('upload success from videoUploadInit',res);
                    callback({
                        identifier:true,
                        data2:data,
                        response:res
                    });
                },
            });
        },

        uploadVideo:function(htmlId,name,ext){
            $(htmlId).uploadify('settings','uploader',configService.getNodeSocketApi() + "/uploadVideo?tenant=" + sessionService.getCustomerId() + sessionService.getUserId()+'&ext='+ext+'&name='+name);
            $(htmlId).uploadify('settings','script',configService.getNodeSocketApi() + "/uploadVideo?tenant=" + sessionService.getCustomerId() + sessionService.getUserId()+'&ext='+ext+'&name='+name);
            $(htmlId).uploadify('upload', '*');
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I had this on the backend:

`form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    res.send(200);
    res.end();
});`

Which was sending a response before I intended it to.